# Convergence of a series of complex numbers.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, entire-functions

> Let $f : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be a non constant entire function. Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^ \infty \frac{1}{n} f(\frac {z}{n})$ converges at any point $z \in \mathbb C$ ?

I think this will not converge but i dont see how to prove this properly.Please help.

Comment: If $f$ is entire, the it has a Taylor Series representation.  If $f(0)\ne 0$, what can one deduce?

Comment: @Dr.MV  Are you saying that then in the given series there will be a term like $ \frac {a_0}{n}$, hence will diverge?

Comment: And if $f(0)=0$, one can estimate $f(z/n)$ using $f'(0)$, hence...

Comment: "I think this will not converge" Really? Which explicit cases did you check?

Comment: @Did Like if $f$ is polynomial with non zero term it seems like it will diverge.

Comment: Sure, and if you arrived there, you may have had the idea of looking at f a polynomial zero at zero... Seems like an awful lot is missing from your post, no?

Comment: @Did sorry.. i dint mention that in the post i thought its a trivial case.

Comment: This is a pity since putting two or three "trivial cases" like these together would lead you directly at a full solution.

Comment: @Did So in case of $f(0)$ nonzero does my above comment work?

Comment: The result holds -- and you do not explain how to prove it.

Comment: @Did I commented something after the initial suggestion of power series,does that work?

Comment: @Did Could you please tell me more about the case when $f(0)=0$?

Comment: You know what? I can read... and, *as already explicitely mentioned*, I see no explanations from you about how to prove the result, in comments or elsewhere.

Comment: @Did sorry..if  $f(0) \neq 0$ therefore $f(z) =\sum a_n z^n$ where $a_0 \neq 0$ Hence putting this in the series of the question we get the series in the question is $\sum (\frac {a_0}{n}+a_1 \frac {z}{n^2}+a_2 \frac {z^2}{n^3}+...)$. But  as $\sum \frac {a_0}{n}$ diverges hence the series in the question will diverge.Is it okay? Sorry for troubling you

Comment: The result holds -- and the "hence the series in the question will diverge" step needs more serious justifications.

Comment: @Did Could you please tell what do i need to add in the argument?

Comment: That the second part of the series converges, obviously, otherwise we could be in a (diverges)+(diverges)=(converges) situation.

Comment: @Did Is it because all series there are of the form $\sum \frac {1}{n^p}$ where $p>1$ ?

Comment: This counts, yes, but you have an infinite number of them hence the argument does not suffice.

Comment: @Did I think the second full series will converge to $\frac {f(0)-a_0}{z}$ for $z \neq 0$ and to $0$ if $z=0$ ?

Comment: Think $\ne$ Prove. (Which was already said *five* times, hence I stop here.)